# Bootstrap navbar dropdown is partly hidden in IE8 - why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project where everything works fine in newer browsers, but not in IE8 as I test with.

The dropdown menu works, but is hidden behind the main content area called `<div class=".container.justering">`

**See the code here: 
http://blanken.redigering.net/tester.html**

In Chrome the drop down menu works great. In IE 11 it works great. In IE8 it hides behind the main container.

It looks like the `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">` behaves like it has an `overflow:hidden;` but it has not.

Comment: Have you tried the `z-index` property?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I may have mixed it up. I tried z-index: 999 on the .navbar-inverse and z-index:777; on the .container.justering . But I may have forgotten to add a position:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `z-index` to the Bootstrap `.dropdown` class (simply override it in your CSS file) should solve your problem.

Note that `z-index` will not work on a static element, like `.navbar-inverse`.

Elements must be positioned, e.g. relatively or absolutely.

Also `z-index` value shouldn't be random, but just as high/low as it needs to be.

If this doesn't fix it, I remember to have read somewhere that IE8 has issues with CSS `filter` property, which is used throughout Bootstrap css for gradients etc.

The solution is to add filter:none!important; to an element like `.navbar` or `.navbar-inner` or `.dropdown`.

Here's [where I read about it](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6548).

I hope it helps.

Comment: I added this now: `.dropdown {z-index:1 !important;}` but it doesn't help in the IE8 I currently have open. It has position:relative; by default css.

Comment: @Preben Have you tried adding higher values? To override Bootstrap CSS you need to apply this `position: relative; z-index: 9;` to `.dropdown`

Comment: Just added `.dropdown {position: relative; z-index: 9 !important;}` Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: Sorry @Preben I'm only testing with IE11 emulation, so I can't reproduce exactly.

Comment: No problem. Did it work in IE11 with emulation with z-index, but not without?

Comment: @Preben I think the emulation is missing something out, but I thought `z-index` as it. However, check my updated answer please.

Comment: I just tested to delete `background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#34388C', endColorstr='#34388C', GradientType=0) !important;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);!important; ` from my CSS - and that fixed the issue. Looked like we got this at the same time ;-)

Comment: @Preben Haha, don't tell me my answer is worthless!! ;) Glad we got it though!

Comment: Absolutely worth "every penny". I am just making the final CSS edits to make it work properly :-)

Answer (score 0):

From Bootstrap:

> Internet Explorer 8 and 9 are also supported, however, please be aware that some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements are not fully supported by these browsers. In addition, Internet Explorer 8 requires the use of Respond.js to enable media query support.

[Bootstrap link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9)

This can be related to css3 support or mainly just that internett explorer8 is way out of date.

If you need a fix for IE 8 specific:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Norwegian use of IE 8 is declining fast (HALLELUJAH):

[Browser support](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-NO-monthly-201312-201412-bar)

I have no way of testing your problem since i don't have access to IE 8.

Comment: Which bit would be CSS3 in the OP situation?

Comment: I know IE8 is out of date. But some of my clients must use old fashioned IE because of compatibility problems with other stuff :-(  I think I have all I need in the `head` to boost compability with the IE8.